# Remote Desktop Connection crashing when connecting to WSL/Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rdp, xfce, xrdp

I am trying to run XFCE Desktop Environment for Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL (not WSL2, fyi. My laptop does not support virtualisation).

I have installed `xrdp`, `xfce4` and `xubuntu-desktop` using `sudo apt install <package-name>`.

I have also rechecked, and even restarted the xrdp service using `sudo service xrdp status` and `sudo service xrdp restart`. The service does seem to be running.

But upon trying to connect to the Remote Desktop using `Remote Desktop Connection`(mstsc), it establishes a connection, seems to confirm that the authentication is correct and simply closes (no desktop is shown).

Here's the log from `xrdp.log`

```
[20210409-13:25:26] [INFO ] connected client computer name: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[20210409-13:25:26] [INFO ] Non-TLS connection established from ::ffff:172.20.10.2 port 52251: encrypted with standard RDP security
[20210409-13:25:27] [DEBUG] xrdp_00002395_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
[20210409-13:25:27] [INFO ] Cannot find keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00020409.ini
[20210409-13:25:27] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000409.ini
[20210409-13:25:27] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00020409 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20210409-13:25:33] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
[20210409-13:25:34] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20210409-13:25:34] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20210409-13:25:34] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20210409-13:25:34] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 10
[20210409-13:25:34] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: started connecting
[20210409-13:25:38] [DEBUG] Closed socket 16 (AF_UNIX)
[20210409-13:25:38] [INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=9109 connected to X11rdp_pid=9112 X11rdp_uid=1000 X11rdp_gid=1000 client_ip=::ffff:172.20.10.2 client_port=52251
[20210409-13:25:38] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connected ok
[20210409-13:25:38] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: chansrv connect successful
[20210409-13:25:38] [DEBUG] Closed socket 15 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 52252)
[20210409-13:25:41] [INFO ] The following channel is allowed: rdpdr (0)
[20210409-13:25:41] [INFO ] The following channel is allowed: rdpsnd (1)
[20210409-13:25:41] [INFO ] The following channel is allowed: cliprdr (2)
[20210409-13:25:41] [INFO ] The following channel is allowed: drdynvc (3)
[20210409-13:25:41] [DEBUG] The allow channel list now initialized for this session
[20210409-13:25:46] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20210409-13:25:46] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:172.20.10.2 port 3389)
[20210409-13:25:46] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20210409-13:25:46] [DEBUG] Closed socket 16 (AF_UNIX)
```

I have tried connecting using `127.0.0.1` as well as `172.20.10.2`, both which yield same result.

I have also tried editing the `/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh` like I saw in the Internet (Commenting out the last two lines and adding `startxfce4`). It doesn't seem to be making any difference.

*P.S Please do not recommend solutions of using `XLaunch`, `XMing` or such similar local Xserver apps. Those do work succesfully, but I am choosing to go for RDP for specific reasons.*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by uncommenting the command
`#exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession` by opening file `sudo nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh`

Comment: I'm having the same problem and command `#exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession` in file `sudo nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh` was already uncommented for me. (but in WSL2)

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the accepted answer, if the line `test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession` is already uncommented but your RDP connection crashes, then comment the existing lines and add a new line `startxfce4`. So the last lines of the file `/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh` should be:

```
# test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
# exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession

startxfce4
```